Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository for Brave doesn't support architecture 'i386'
Getting below error message while issuing :
    sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ee.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease               
Hit:5 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu noble InRelease                 
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-security InRelease
Hit:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu noble-apps-updates InRelease
Hit:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:14 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-updates InRelease
Hit:15 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu noble-infra-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
17 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Is this error due to the faulty line for the Brave browser script brave-browser in the /etc/cron.daily/ folder? I.e. 32-bit enabled instead 64-bit?
I checked if the missing [arch=amd64] could be the issue but it is already there as "REPOCONFIG="deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"".
I solved the issue with [arch=amd64] by executing sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list in Terminal. Then  I added [arch=amd64] to the line deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main  so the line looks like this: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main . Then I saved the file and closed gedit and reexecuted the sudo apt update command without any errors.

You mention having a arch=amd64 for a google repository; but the error message relating to i386 relates to a different brave repository, implying you've not added a restriction to amd64 for that repository.  Re-read your question & you should note your error (or missing detail at the very least that highlights a user misstep in the question)

I really do have that google repository line in the brave browser script. It came as installed.

Yes, but you need to specify amd64 only for https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com as well... ie. your current details tell your machine to download amd64 only from google, and amd64 + i386 from brave as you've not put any restriction there... thus the error you're asking about.  Google & Brave are different repositories; you need to restrict both individually.
